# how do I view cookies sent in python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I want to be able to read the cookies that are being sent from a request so I can import them.

```
import requests
URL = 'https://secure.net.wwe.com/enterworkflow.do?flowId=account.login'

Send = requests.get(URL)

print(Send.cookies.get_dict())

Desired Output:
>>>> cookies = {'test':'likethis'}
```

I understand how to view set cookies but there is no clear explanation on how to view the cookies that are being sent along with the request.

Comment: Hmmm puzzled as to what your problem is as when I tried that code I got {'SESSION_1': 'wf_flowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login%7Estage%3D%3D%3D3%7EflowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login'} which seems to match the desired pattern.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. That's the cookie being received, when I intercept the traffic on my network it shows their are cookies sent. I need those specific cookies that are being sent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you get cookies from the response with python requests is with the cookie jar.

```
    >>> import requests
>>> URL = 'https://secure.net.wwe.com/enterworkflow.do?flowId=account.login'
>>>
>>> Send = requests.get(URL)
>>> Send.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='SESSION_1', value='wf_flowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login%7Estage%3D%3D%3D3%7EflowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.wwe.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

To convert this response to a dict you can use the below method

```
>>> requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(Send.cookies)
{'SESSION_1': 'wf_flowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login%7Estage%3D%3D%3D3%7EflowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login'}
```

But you asked about what cookies are sent with your request...This is perplexing so I decided to dive in and see what I could find.

You can see if python has any cookies in the cookiejar by creating a session and calling the cookiejar method.

```
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> session.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]> //No Cookies?
>>> session.get(URL)
   <Response [200]>
>>> requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)
{'SESSION_1': 'wf_flowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login%7Estage%3D%3D%3D3%7EflowId%3D%3D%3Daccount.login'} //Cookies!
```

or just calling the cookiejar

```
>>> print requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

So this was enough proof for me that no cookies were sent. AFAIK, cookies wont get sent with requests.get unless you explicitly set them. To prove this, I ran your request thru Burp Suite.

```
>>> http = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
>>> https = "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
>>> ftp = "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
>>> proxy_dict = {
...   "http": http,
...   "https": https,
...   "ftp": ftp
... }
>>> Send = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxy_dict, verify=False)
```

and this is what the request looks like in Burp

[image]

Comment: When I use fiddler to intercept the traffic this is what's shown when I enter the URL.  There are more cookies that are being sent in the request. https://image.prntscr.com/image/OgyEnQu8Q0OnIkub7N6Kuw.png